# Display an image with spring boot hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

When I try to add an image in Base64 from a Product Object, like next:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
        <td><img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${product.image}}" /></td>
        <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
        <td th:if="${product.state==true}" th:text="Activo" style="color:green;"></td>  
        <td th:if="${product.state==false}" th:text="Bloqueado" style="color:red;"></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-form">Editar</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Eliminar</a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

the `{$product.image}` has the value `[B@776a398` but if I put in a LOG.Info(); this show me the `based64 string`. How can I solve it?

This is my Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/products") 
public ModelAndView index(){

    User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    ModelAndView mvn = new ModelAndView();
    mvn.addObject("user",userServiceImpl.getOne(user.getUsername()));

    List<Product> products  = productServiceImpl.getAll();

    for(Product product : products)
    {
        byte[] encode = Base64.getEncoder().encode(product.getImage());
        product.setImage(encode);
        LOG.info(new String(encode));
    }

    mvn.addObject("products",products);
    mvn.setViewName(view);
    LOG.info("Se ha ingresado al controlador de productos");
    return mvn;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your logger is just showing the base64 encoding because you're code does it. See `LOG.info(new String(encode));` in your products loop

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder--

Comment: in theory i m specting that encode to show an image , and that it is ok that i want to show but  the problem is when i put this <td><img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${product.image}}" /></td> with reference ${product.image} it should displat something las this iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA58AAADpCAIAAAAs4.... but only shows this [B@776a398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the value of the product image:

```
 <img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${product.image}}" />
```

Thymeleaf is just doing a `toString()` of your byte[], in java the default toString() gets some non readable values and that is what thymeleaf is adding to the src.

From the official doc:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

So if you need to get the same as is showing in your logger you could  use a method which returns it as String:

```
public class Product {

    //...
    public String getImageEncoded() {
         return new String(this.image);
    }

}
```

And then in thymeleaf use this method:

```
<img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${product.getImageEncoded()}}" />
```